# How to properly center two overlaid symbols?

Tags: math-operators, overlays

I have found several answers related to overlaying symbols, but none of them worked for me, maybe because they require deeper knowledge of tex to be usable.
I ended up with this solution, but the symbol centers are not properly aligned and the `\mathlarger` command seems to be very slow to be used nested.

My intent is to have a plus sign with a dot in the center which is large enough to be clearly noticed, but without cluttering the operator.

Another possibility is to have a normal-sized dot surrounded by blank space over the plus sign.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{relsize}

\newcommand{\C}{{\mathrlap{
\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{
    \cdot
}}}
}}+} 

\begin{document}
Formula:
$A \C B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no hard and fast rule for centering overlaid symbols, precisely because the empty buffer around each symbol can vary, based on the font designer's wishes, and not necessarily be symmetric.

That said, one can adjust to account for the particular glyphs at hand

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine,graphicx}
\newcommand\dotplus{\mathbin{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackinset{c}{}{c}{-.2\LMpt}%
  {\SavedStyle\scaleobj{.6}{\bullet}}{\SavedStyle+}}}}}
\begin{document}
$x\dotplus y$

$\scriptstyle x\dotplus y$

$\scriptscriptstyle x\dotplus y$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A variant, using a simple text dot:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand{\varC}{\mathbin{\stackMath{\stackinset{c}{0pt}{c}{0pt}{\textbf{\Large.}}{ + }}}}

\begin{document}

Formula: $A\varC B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Another possibility is to have a normal-sized dot surrounded by blank space over the plus sign.

This sound like `\dotplus`, and IMHO, this option is better, or even `\dot{+}` (only a bit different).

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\Huge\[\dotplus\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant a dot overlaid/juxtaposed visually in front of a plus sign.